# AWS ECS containers - ELB health checks close the container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create multiple WordPress instances on ECS containers.

I have a task definition where i set up 2 containers for WordPress
- 1 WordPress container with host port 0 (per AWS documentation)
- 1 MySQL container

Network is bridge

I create a service with an Application Load Balancer and "Health check grace period" of 200 sec. Via AWS interface i add the WordPress container in load balancer and set port 80 as Production listener port.  See screenshot http://prntscr.com/p7s30z

After i create the service, the task start running and the containers are working for a short period. I can access the WordPress install on a ip:port url(for ex: http://54.236.31.249:32768/ ), and i can even do the setup and publish a post. However in 2-3 minutes the containers get stopped and in task page i see

```
Stopped reason: Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:548086034478:targetgroup/cretutarget/e3a5f331c35eece1)
```

I use a security group that is very permissive and the Wordpress containers is accessible in the first moments.

For that target group the health checks looks like this : http://prntscr.com/p7s8u5

Any idea why the ELB health checks fails ?

Answer (score 0):

Where are the php/html files stored for this wordpress database? I would check to make sure that the ALB Security Group has access to where the files are located or the security group your ECS instances are at. Also, make sure you use the root path '/' for the health check.

Comment: Also, if you used AWS ECS, it should have setup the correct ports for you with the ALB and ECS instance

Comment: This is my wp container definition http://prntscr.com/p7wn3q , so files are stored inside container. root path is '/' . security group is the same and is a very permisive one. Also the wp container is fully functional for 1-2 min until the health check runs.Thanks

Comment: Can you do a curl of the local host of the physical ECS instance and inside the container ?  Also, the files are stored in the container ? Do you mean the DB container or mounted EFS ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the health check URL is getting a redirect to the WordPress setup page or login page. By default a Target Group health check expect a status code of `200` to be returned, not a `301` redirect. You can test this by watching your browser's network tab as you try to go to the `/` path on your WordPress site, and see what status code it returns. If that status code isn't `200` then you'll need to add the other status code (`301` or whatever it is returning) in your target group's health check settings at least temporarily until you get the site configured and returning `200` on the `/` path.